# Post a Variable into Database using Input Tag

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have created an image uploader using asp.net mvc that posts images into database. but i want to add an input to send related url into sql server DB.
for view section i have defined two inputs like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Choose File:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
   <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" class="custom-file-input" /><br />
     <input type="text" id="urlname" name="urlname" class="form-control" />
     <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
    </div>
     <div class="input-group-append">
     <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Upload" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

and for controller i've created a post command to send data into database. but i don't know what to place inside URL Path variable.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadSliderImage(HttpPostedFileBase fileupload)
    {
        if (fileupload != null)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.FileName);
            int fileSize = fileupload.ContentLength;
            int Size = fileSize / 1000;
            fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SliderImages/" + fileName));

            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddNewSliderImage", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSize", Size);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FilePath", "~/SliderImages/" + fileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URLPath", ??);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UploadSliderImage");
    }
```

And here's my table and procedures which i've created to store data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CarouselSlider](  
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
[FileSize] [int] NULL,  
[FilePath] [nvarchar](100) NULL,  
[URLPath] [varchar](100) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_CarouselSlider] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
(  
[ID] ASC  
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
) ON [PRIMARY]  

GO  

CREATE procedure [dbo].[spAddNewSliderImage]  
(  
 @Name nvarchar(50),  
 @FileSize int,  
 @FilePath nvarchar(100),
 @URLPath varchar(100)  
)  
as  
begin  
insert into CarouselSlider(Name,FileSize,FilePath,URLPath)   
values (@Name,@FileSize,@FilePath,@URLPath)   
end  

CREATE procedure [dbo].[spGetAllSliderImage]  
as  
begin  
Select ID,Name,FileSize,FilePath,URLPath from CarouselSlider   
end
```

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer and here it is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadSliderImage(string urlname)
{
  string URL = urlname;
    ....
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URLPath", URL);
}
```